# Google Assistant automatically ends Conversation Action

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

When creating a Conversation Action with API.AI, there are certain words (close, exit, cancel) where the Google Home/Assistant automatically ends the interaction with your Conversation Action without sending a request.

Is there a way to override these Conversation-killing words so that a value of 'close' may be included in the webhook? I wish to accept 'close' as application input, and continue the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a 'quit' intent (with few words you would like the user to end the conversation) and you got a webhook connect to your Fulfillment - it will send your webhook the 'close' value.

You can see a working example here: https://github.com/greenido/bitcoin-info-action

Comment: I'm confused. In your example code, the "quit" intent doesn't use webhook fulfillment and there is no action in your code setup to handle it.

Comment: Furthermore, if you *do* attach a webhook to it, and you use the "quit" statement, the webhook isn't called. (At least when in preview mode.)

Comment: In my example, I didn't needed the value from 'quit' but if you need it, you can get it as any other intent (e.g. 'tota'l), just make sure to end the conversation after you are getting the value.

Comment: Btw, have you made sure that you clicked on 'use webhook' in the fulfilment of your intent?

Comment: Yup, I'm sure. Are you sure you tested saying "quit" and that it called the webhook and/or said your phrase instead of just quitting?

Comment: Yes, It's working for me. The webhook is being called.